# Positioning a node horizontally aligned and below others

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Using tikz 3.0.0, I want to create the following diagram

[image: commutative diagram1]

which I have so far achieved by manually positioning the “G” in the last row:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) {$(G×G)×G$};
        \node (B) [right=of A] {$G×(G×G)$};
        \node (C) [below left=of A] {$G×G$};
        \node (D) [below right=of B] {$G×G$};
        \node (E) at (1.5,-3) {$G$};
        \draw[double equal sign distance] (A) -- node[above]{$\sim$} (B);

        \draw[->] (A) -- node[above left]{\small $μ × \id$} (C);
        \draw[->] (B) -- node[above right]{\small $\id × μ$} (D);
        \draw[->] (C) -- node[above]{\small $μ$} (E);
        \draw[->] (D) -- node[above]{\small $μ$} (E);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Can I do this without maually setting “G” `at (1.5,-3)` using positioning?

On a related note, I tried to do the same with {tikz-cd} and got:
[image: commutative diagram2]
using the following code:

```
\begin{displaymath}
    \begin{tikzcd} 
        & (G × G) × G \ar[dl, "μ × \id"] \ar[rr, equal, "\sim"] & & G × (G × G) \ar[dr, "\id × μ"] & \\ 
        G × G \ar[drr, "μ"] & & & & G × G \ar[dll, "μ"] \\ 
         & & G & & 
    \end{tikzcd} 
\end{displaymath}
```

Can I somehow achieve a picture without an unnecessarily stretched equal sign, that is a picture more like the one above, but using {tikz-cd}?

I’m using TeXLive, version 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one possible solution. However, my `tikz` is not 3.0.0 so I need to change some of your math code `\mu` and `times`. Also this solution uses `double` for equal sign, not `double equal sign distance` as the OP used. IMHO, the principle applies if the related math quantities is changed to those applicable in tikz 3.0.0. The bottom G position is determined via the code below where given (A) and (B), their center is determined automatically. That is the (1.5,-3) is removed.

```
\node[yshift=-3cm] (E) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {$G$};  %change yshift for one's need.
```

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[paper size={15cm,6cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,positioning}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (A) {$(G\times G)\times G$};
        \node (B) [right=1cm of A] {$G\times (G\times G)$};
        \node (C) [below left=of A] {$G\times G$};
        \node (D) [below right=of B] {$G\times G$};
%        \node (E) at (1.5,-3) {$G$};
\node[yshift=-3cm] (E) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) {$G$};
        \draw[double] (A) -- node[above]{$\sim$} (B);

        \draw[->] (A) -- node[above left]{\small $\mu \times id$} (C);
        \draw[->] (B) -- node[above right]{\small $id \times \mu$} (D);
        \draw[->] (C) -- node[above]{\small $\mu$} (E);
        \draw[->] (D) -- node[above]{\small $\mu$} (E);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the solution! The matrix nature of {tikz-cd} makes such an approach impossible, right?

Comment: For `tikzcd` `column sep=xx` is a global setting for the entire matrix node. So, yes, tikz is flexible.